# Trying to compare two different arrays using Numpy equal function however returning True every time

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compare two 9 by 9 array's in Jupiter notebook, however it always returns they are equal even though the numbers are different. Here are the two arrays and the code I am trying:

```
sudoku:
[[1 7 4 3 8 2 9 5 6]
 [2 9 5 4 6 7 1 3 8]
 [3 8 6 9 5 1 4 7 2]
 [4 6 1 5 2 3 8 9 7]
 [7 3 8 1 4 9 6 2 5]
 [9 5 2 8 7 6 3 1 4]
 [5 2 9 6 3 4 7 8 1]
 [6 1 7 2 9 8 5 4 3]
 [8 4 3 7 1 5 2 6 9]]

self.start_sudoku:
[[1 0 4 3 8 2 9 5 6]
 [2 0 5 4 6 7 1 3 8]
 [3 8 6 9 5 1 4 0 2]
 [4 6 1 5 2 3 8 9 7]
 [7 3 8 1 4 9 6 2 5]
 [9 5 2 8 7 6 3 1 4]
 [5 2 9 6 3 4 7 8 1]
 [6 0 7 2 9 8 5 4 3]
 [8 4 3 0 1 5 2 6 9]]
```

Here is the code I am working with"

```
np.array_equal(sudoku, self.start_sudoku)
```

it returns True even though the numbers are different in the two arrays, what am I doing wong?

Comment: I cannot replicate the error you're seeing. With those two arrays, `np.array_equal` is returning (properly) `False`.

Comment: In PyCharm it works, however when I try in Jupyter Notebook, it is always True, very strange

Comment: I would suggest restarting your kernel in your notebook, to ensure that there aren't any older variables interfering. When I tested it, I tested it in a jupyter notebook as well, so I don't believe that's your issue.

Comment: @NK i am unable to replicate the problem in jupyter notebook too. `np.array_equal` is returning (properly) `False`

Comment: ok, after restarting my machine it works properly now, thank you Raymond